# How to fix Unity Rigidbody.AddForce problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bounce pad (jump pad if you like it like that). I wanted do make it bounce you OnTriggerEnter, which i have done using Rigidbody.AddForce.

And my problem is that it once bounces you higher, once lower, and sometimes does not bounce at all, you just fall on it.

Here's my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BouncerBouncing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bounceForce;

    public Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if(collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerRigidbody.AddForce(0, bounceForce, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A bounce pad would commonly not be using triggers, but a non-trigger Rigidbody which listens for OnCollisionEnter. Then, you would apply a Physics Material to that body which has bounciness at the highest (1.0) and uses the Maximum combine option for bounces. Now test, and if that bounciness isn't enough, bring back your AddForce code in the OnCollisionEnter function, and ensure that bounceForce is appropriately high for it to have effect.

Answer (score 0):

Applying an inpulse of force won't cancel any contrary motion. For example, if you're falling down and your Y velocity is -10, applying an impulse with a velocity of 10 upwards will give you a total of 0. If you want to replace your Y velocity, you can directly set the velocity instead of applying force.

```
playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(playerRigidbody.velocity.x, bounceForce, playerRigidbody.velocity.z);
```

This line simply replaces the Y velocity with the jump force while keeping the X and Z values as they were. This way, the bounce height will remain constant.